# HTTP-Accept header is different on several methods

Tags: java, php, http, header, httprequest

I'm trying to get a request's http-accept header and I get different values when I get the header from

1. Java -  `req.getHeader("Accept") + req.getHeader("Accept-Encoding") + req.getHeader("accept-language")`
2. PHP - `'<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'].$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'].$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']; ?>`

The results are :

1. `*/*gzip,deflate,sdchen-US,en;q=0.8`
2. `text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8gzip,deflate,sdchen-US,en;q=0.8`

How come they are different?

Am I getting them wrong?

Comment: What is the type of `req`?

Comment: For Java, please show the lines of code where you are getting the headers, and then how you're validating their contents (printing/logging them, or debugging)

Answer (score 1):

PHP is returning all of the request parameters while your Java HTTP client is only returning one.

The `HttpServletRequest` method provides the [`getHeaders(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getHeaders%28java.lang.String%29) that

> Returns all the values of the specified request header as an
>   `Enumeration` of `String` objects.

So use that.

Notice how the Java result (split to account for the `String` concatenation you are doing)

```
*/*                                                                          */
^ the last 'Accept' header value

gzip,deflate,sdch 
^ the 'Accept-Encoding'

en-US,en;q=0.8
^ the 'Accept-Language'
```

I'm not exactly sure why it doesn't do it for the other headers.

---

This would be much clearer from the start if your output was easier to read. Don't just concatenate Strings like that. Use a separator of some sort.